# Generating sets of $Q_8$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Consider the matrices 
$$I=\left( {\begin{array}{ccc}
   1 & 0 \\
    0 & 1 \\
  \end{array} } \right), \qquad A=\left( {\begin{array}{ccc}
   i & 0 \\
    0 & i \\
  \end{array} } \right), \qquad B=\left( {\begin{array}{ccc}
   0 & -1 \\
    1 & 0 \\
  \end{array} } \right), \qquad C= AB$$
by definition, so $$C=\left( {\begin{array}{ccc}
   0 & -i \\
    -i & 0 \\
  \end{array} } \right)$$ in $M_2(\mathbb{C}).$ Direct matrix calculations show that $AB=C, BC=A, CA=B$ and $A^2=B^2=C^2=-I$. I have already shown that $$BA=-AB=-C$$ $$CB=-BC=-A$$ $$AC=-CA=-B$$ and $$A^{-1}=-A, B^{-1}=-B, C^{-1}=-C.$$ My problem is that how do I prove that the multiplicative matrix group generated by $A, B, C$ is precisely the set of eight matrices $$Q_8 = \left\{ \pm I, \pm A, \pm B, \pm C \right\}.$$ I know that in a group $G$, a subset $X \subset G$ is a generating set for $G$ if every $g \in G$ can
be written as a product of powers of elements taken from $X$. I'm confused to until which power can I write it. Please help as I'm not good at this and that I think I'm over thinking things..

Comment: Hint: Using induction and the fact $A^2 = -I$ shows that any power $A^k$ is one of $\pm I, \pm A$, and analogous statements hold for powers of $B$ and $C$.

Comment: You are overthinking things.  You've shown by brute force that the given set $Q_8$ is multiplicatively closed.